# Get House Price data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab the house price along with the address, and hopefully other relevant data (bedrooms?). I have got the following so far. Using google's element inspection I can see that there is a  element, but if I search for this I won't get the address.

Any thoughts?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query='http://www.realestate.com.au/buy/with-2-bedrooms-in-epping%2c+nsw+2121/list-1?maxBeds=2&source=refinements'
resp = requests.get(query)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
ads=soup.findAll("div", {"id": "searchResultsTbl"})
```

Comment: Why would someone vote this down?

Comment: Probably because you don't have a specific question like "how to get address and bedrooms". Or maybe it's because code that you provided doesn't do anything specific and doesn't show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get address use this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query='http://www.realestate.com.au/buy/with-2-bedrooms-in-epping%2c+nsw+2121/list-1?maxBeds=2&source=refinements'
resp = requests.get(query)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
ads = soup.find("div", {"class": "vcard"})
print ads.h2.a.text
```

Output:

```
61 Mobbs Lane, Epping, NSW 2121
```

---

For all addresses use this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
ads = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "vcard"})
for ad in ads:
    print ad.h2.a.text
```

Output:

```
61 Mobbs Lane, Epping, NSW 2121
29/3-5 Kandy Avenue, Epping, NSW 2121
5/30 Cambridge Street, Epping, NSW 2121
...
101/239-243 Carlingford Rd, Carlingford, NSW...
65-69 Adderton Road, Telopea, NSW 2117
```

---

And for rooms you can use something like this:

```
rooms = soup.findAll("li", {"class":"first"})
for room in rooms:
    if room.span:
        print room.span.text
```